# Complete Instruction set

Tags: instructions, instruction-set

Consider a hypothetical computer with a main memory M having a capacity of 2n−1 n-bit words. The CPU contains an n-bit accumulator AC and an (n−1)-bit program counter PC.It has a repertoire of two n-bit instructions in which the leftmost bits is the opcode and the remaining bits form the address in M. The first instruction is called SUBS (Subract and store). SUBS X causes the following microinstructions to take place:

AC ← AC − M(X)

M(X) ← AC

PC←PC+1

The second instruction is an unconditional branch JUMP X which causes the following operation to take place:

PC ← M(X(0 : n − 2))

A word in M can be either an instruction (SUBS or JUMP) or a fixed-point binary number in twos-
complement code. Prove informally that the following operations can be programmed:-

(a) The memory data transfers AC ← M(X) and M(X) ← AC.

(b) The addition operation AC ← AC + M(X)

Comment: What is your question??

Answer (score 0):

For neither of the two do you require the JUMP X instruction. Keep a memory location, say M(0), that will hold the value 0. This is justified because it says "A word in M can be either an instruction or a fixed-point binary number". Use this, to solve the problem.

Note: It will take quite a few operations to perform the desired operations.